# Find a symmetric positive-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I need to find a symmetric matrix A
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
such that its' main minors are positive, but not all the elements on diagonal are. I.e. (without loss of generality) the following conditions have to be satisfied:

1) $a_{11}>0$

2) $a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2>0$

3) $\det(A)>0$

4) $a_{33} < 0$

I tried to find it but it seems that there's no such matrix (although I can not prove it). The conditions seem to be connected one to another and probably even contradictive with each other. Maybe, it can not be done with 3 by 3 matrices but can be with ones of higher size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done if your matrix has real entries. By [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), if all leading principal minors of a real symmetric matrix are positive, the matrix itself must be positive definite and hence its diagonal entries are also positive.

However, it is possible that all leading principal minors of a *complex symmetric* matrix are positive, while some diagonal entries are negative. Consider for instance
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&2i\\ 0&2i&-1}.
$$

Comment: " matrix itself must be positive definite, hence its diagonal entries are also positive"
-But why? The first two diagonal entries are positive, yes, but the third one, why should it also be positive? Are all entries of positive defined matrix positive?

Comment: @AlexJohnson If $A$ is positive definite (not "positive defined"; there is no such terminology), then $x^TAx>0$ for every nonzero vector $x$. When $x^T=(1,0,0)$, this means $a_{33}>0$.